# Defining rules for anti-commutative multiplication

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am trying to create products following an anti-commutative rules using the binary operator `**`. I define my rules the following way:

```
before___ ** a_ ** b_ ** after___ :>  
  If[OrderedQ[{a, b}] == True,
    before ** a ** b ** after,
    before ** ((-1)*b) ** a ** after],
NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] :> x
```

This does half the job that I want, since it transforms the following expression

$$o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}-o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,3}-o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{2,3}+o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}+o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}-o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}$$

into

$$2 o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}-2 o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,3}+2 o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}\text{**}o_{1,2}$$

I ultimately want to reduce the expression to

$$ 6 o_{1,2}\text{**}o_{1,3}\text{**}o_{2,3}$$

(Please add the appropriate tags for this question as I didn't find anything I deem suitable).

Comment: It would be better to have actual input (in `InputForm`) that can be copy-pasted, rather than a LaTex rendering.

Comment: `If[cond == True, ...]` $\to$ `If[cond, ...]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using `CenterDot` wrapper for the multiplication symbol instead of `NonCommutativeMultiply`. The former, just as the latter, does not commute terms by default, but it also has no pre-defined properties in Mathematica, which makes it easy to assign new properties to it:

```
ClearAll[CenterDot]
CenterDot[x___, CenterDot[y___], z___] := CenterDot[x, y, z]
CenterDot[x___, q_ CenterDot[y___], z___] :=q CenterDot[x, y, z]
CenterDot[x___, Times[-1, CenterDot[y___]], z___] :=- CenterDot[x, y, z]
CenterDot[x___, y_ + z_, q___] := CenterDot[x, y, q] + CenterDot[x, z, q]
CenterDot[x___, y_ Subscript[o_, a_, b_], z___] := y CenterDot[x, Subscript[o, a, b], z]
CenterDot[x___, Times[-1, Subscript[o_, a_, b_]], z___] := - CenterDot[x, Subscript[o, a, b], z]
CenterDot[x___,y_,z___]/;FreeQ[y,Subscript[o_, a_, b_]]:=y CenterDot[x,z]
CenterDot[x_]:=x
CenterDot[]:=1
CenterDot[x___] /; ! OrderedQ[{x}] := Signature[{x}] CenterDot[Sort[{x}] /. List -> Sequence]
```

This directly leads to

```
Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 2, 3] - Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 2, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 3] - 
Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 2, 3] + Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 2, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 2] + 
Subscript[o, 2, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 3] - Subscript[o, 2, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 2]
```

> [image]

Comment: Hello. What new rule should I set if I get things like `1 \[CentralDot] Subscript[o,a,b] - Subscript[o,a,b]` and `-(1 \[CentralDot] Subscript[o,a,b]) + Subscript[o,a,b]` ?

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona added three more rules that should do this.

Comment: That is great, thank you!

Comment: I have another problem now. I had the expression `(-3*1 \[CenterDot] (-Subscript[t, 1, 2]) \[CenterDot] 
     Subscript[t, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] (-Subscript[t, 2, 3]) + 
   3*1 \[CenterDot] 
     Subscript[t, 1, 
      2] \[CenterDot] (-Subscript[t, 1, 3]) \[CenterDot] 
     Subscript[t, 2, 3])/(24*Pi^2)`

with the previous set of rules. Now with these rules this term goes to `0` instead of 6 the expression

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona a really important subtlety is that the rules treat only quantities that look like `Subscript[o,_,_]` as operators, while everything else is treated as a constant. So the `Subscript[t,_,_]` quantities are treated as constants. If you need both, `Subscript[o,_,_]` AND `Subscript[t,_,_]` to be treated as operators, you could make the pattern look like `Subscript[_,_,_]` -- so any symbol with two subscripts would be anticommuting with any other symbol that fits this description. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona Try the updated rules (make sure all appear in the current order). This implements the anti-commutator algebra $\{A_{i,j},B_{k,l}\}=0$ where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary operator names that are either the same or different.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.